# How to remove groups within a string in order?

Tags: javascript, regex

My goal is to pull chunks of 0's or 1's from a binary string. Using regex.match to look for patterns pulls out all chunks and loses order. I need to be able to pass any length of binary to it. How can I correctly pull out chunks so that '10011000001' -> '1', '00', '11', '00000', '1'?

I can only think to run a loop to count the number of changes from 0 to 1 then run alternating regex.match() on it, but that's certainly inefficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could look for a digit and look for more of the same group.

```js
var string = '10011000001',
    parts = string.match(/([01])\1*/g);

console.log(parts);
```

Comment: That is great! Thanks! Can you explain to me some of these features? I'm still getting my bearings with Regex. So () sets up a capture group and that checks for either 0 or 1 to start capture, right? Then \1 sets it up to repeat ignoring previous captures? What exactly does * do here?

Comment: `*` is the quantifier, which takes zero or up to all matching items. in this case it looks for the same group values, even if no one is found.